# SIGMA fp intermittently not recognizing SSD connected via USB-C port

Tags: sigma, cables

To rule out the obvious suspects:

- The SSD is right. Samsung T5, recorded a lot of 12bit 4K CinemaDNG with this very camera on it.
- The cable performance is right. Not the original T5 cable—I lost it and it’s nowhere to be sold—but it’s Apple’s own fully compliant USB-C and TB4 high speed data cable, and it did work for recording before (and still does… occasionally).

For months now I am having issues with fp being stuck at the “Now connecting…” screen at startup (with SSD connected), and recently it’s gotten so bad that I can spend minutes fiddling and re-plugging the cable and restarting the camera until it gets beyond that screen and sees the SSD properly.

In addition, recently it started randomly losing connection even after it’s recognized at camera startup, and I have just seen for the first time a screen saying that the USB device is not responding at some point.

It’s almost certainly not the cable going bad, as it’s very new and also quite rugged. Is it perhaps my SSD performance degrading, or (gasp) camera’s USB-C port slowly falling apart? Has anyone had similar issues that were resolved in some way?

Comment: To narrow things down, try fiddling with the cable at only one end (without moving the other). Also, you can solve a lot of problems n electronics with adequate application of contact cleaner.

Comment: @xenoid Fair enough, let me try that…

Comment: Contact cleaner is the only possible solution perhaps, I will have to find one (never seen anything like this so no idea where it’s even sold). Fiddling the cable as I did before to make it work no longer does anything. It clearly sees that a device is plugged in, since it shows the “Now connecting…” message, but it can’t do anything with it—even the most basic function of formatting media is greyed out. This is running the latest firmware version (4.00)

Comment: Very common thing, for instance [this](https://www.amazon.com/WD-40-Specialist-Electrical-Contact-Cleaner/dp/B00AF0OFVU) (but there are plenty of others).

Comment: Pointer appreciated. I’ll see if I can find it and potentially will check with official Sigma distributor this week in case they are familiar with the issue or see some need for USB-C port to be repaired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Camera issue, USB-C port to PCB connection may be borked.

- I confirmed that the problem is not the cable or SSD using another camera unit at an official distributor
- Distributor rep tried to clean the port to no avail
- Requires sending the camera to Japan for service, which would cost 600–700 USD and 6 weeks

Bummer.